# How to handle new versions of frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: frameworks, twitter-bootstrap

I have started to use frameworks like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), but if Twitter releases a minor update, I'm not sure how to easily update my existing code once I've integrated it into a project. Currently I am just getting the new files and putting them into the directory.

- Is there a simple way to do this, or am I going to have to copy the updated framework files into my project (current method)?
- Is there a way to pull the framework into my current project if I already have a git repo in that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: git checkout -b NewFrameworkVersionTest

Step 2: download new framework files and copy over existing ones

Step 3: add & commit to branch

Step 4: run your build, making sure to execute all automated tests

Step 5: deploy build to test environment

Step 6: perform any manual testing you wish to

Step 7: If no issues, skip to Step 10. else, fix any issues identified

Step 8: commit changes to branch

Step 9: go back to step 4

Step 10: git checkout master

Step 11: git merge NewFrameworkVersionTest

Step 12: deploy to production

Comment: You don't have to do it this way. Just copying over the old files will work too.

Keep in mind, I keep all my edits (to the css and js) in separate files. That way, I avoid having to run though the files, comparing old to new.